# Mail.app starts after sleep or shut down + reopen windows on Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Mail.app keeps opening up when my Mac Mini wakes up from sleep or starts up after shutting down and remembering open windows even though I don't have it open before sleeping or the shutdown.

Is anyone else experiencing this? If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can happen because you have set it up in the login items or some other application (ex: iCal) is starting Mail.app

there is a detailed discussion here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1853470?threadID=1853470

Hope that helps.